# jQuery change cell background to red on negative value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the below dynamic form rows can be added or removed dynamically. Calculation involves finding the difference between cost price and the selling price of a product.

What I like to implement (and trying in vain for the last one week or so) is to set the background color of the result cell to red if the value is negative and to green if the value is positive. Though I came across several solutions on this site unfortunately I was unable to implement them to solve this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS</title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if (rowCount < 5) { // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        //var row = table.insertRow(rowCount-1);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        row.id = 'row_'+rowCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;            
        }
       var listitems= row.getElementsByTagName("input")
            for (i=0; i<listitems.length; i++) {
              listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('"+row.id+"')");
            }
    } else {
        alert("Maximum 5 Rows Only.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if (null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
            if (rowCount <= 1) { // limit the user from removing all the fields
                alert("Cannot Remove all the Records.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}

    </script>
    <script>
    function calculate(elementID) {
        var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
        var num1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=num1]')[0].value;
        var num2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=num2]')[0].value;
        var result = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=result]')[0];
        var result1 = num2 - num1;
        result.value = result1;
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <input type="button" value="Remove" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
    <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr id='row_0'>

                    <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>

                    <td>
                        <label>Cost Price</label>
                        <input type="text" size="1" required="required" name="num1" class="num1" id="num1" oninput="calculate('row_0')"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Selling Price</label>
                        <input type="text" size="1" required="required" name="num2" class="num2" id="num2" oninput="calculate('row_0')"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Difference</label>
                        <input type="text" size="1" required="required" name="result" class="result" id="result" />
                    </td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. - You need to close the second script tag in the header. - You're also missing a closing table tag. - You can't have a paragraph tag directly inside a table row.

Comment: Also you can't have a `p` tag as a direct descendant of a `tr`

Comment: could you please reproduce this in a fiddle..

Comment: @Lal I was going to edit the original post, but the HTML errors stopped me.

Comment: Sorry am editing the post at the moment and not expecting this much immediate reaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the HTML issues (as noted in the comments on your question) you can achieve your goal by checking the `result1` variable is greater than zero, and applying the relevant style to the parent `td` of the `input`. Try this:

```
function calculate(elementID) {
    var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var num1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=num1]')[0].value;
    var num2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=num2]')[0].value;
    var result = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=result]')[0];
    var cell = result.parentElement;
    var result1 = num2 - num1;
    result.value = result1;

    var cellBackground = result1 < 0 ? 'red' : 'transparent';
    cell.style.backgroundColor = cellBackground;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m1j8snj7/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Works a treat.

Comment: @RachelGallen Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate(elementID) {
    var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var num1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=num1]')[0].value;
    var num2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=num2]')[0].value;
    var result = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=result]')[0];
    var result1 = num2 - num1;
    result.value = result1;
    if(result1 < 0){
        $(result).parent().css("background", "red");
    }else{
        $(result).parent().css("background", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Harish Gupta Thank you very much:)